# Connection Reset in Oauth2RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using `Oauth2RestTemplate` with `SSLContext` as

```
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
```

I am getting an intermittent connection reset error as `SocketException`. I've also tried to use `TLSV1.2` for sslContext but still faces the same issue.

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "URL": Connection reset; nested exception is java.net.SocketExcept
ion: Connection reset
```